# Titanium fails to build or emulate android application

Tags: android, android-emulator, titanium, titanium-mobile

I just installed and configured Titanium Studio and it's dependencies to develop my Android applications but none of the applications even the sample app of titanium won't start in emulator.
I can see `Mobile Web Preview` in browser but when I try `Android Emulator` I get the following error in Console:

```
[INFO] Force including all modules...
[INFO] Compiling Javascript Resources ...
[INFO] Compiling localization files
[ERROR] error: more than one emulator
[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 2528, in <module>
[ERROR]     builder.build_and_run(False, avd_id, debugger_host=debugger_host, profiler_host=profiler_host)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 2285, in build_and_run
[ERROR]     self.push_deploy_json()
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 1954, in push_deploy_json
[ERROR]     sdcard_available = self.wait_for_sdcard()
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 1907, in wait_for_sdcard
[ERROR]     if 'SDCARD READY' in output:
[ERROR] TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
[ERROR] :  Build process exited with code 1
[ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 33s 353ms
```

Android emulator opens up and everything looks find but my application fails to build.

I found [this page](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Errors+Building+Titanium+Projects#ErrorsBuildingTitaniumProjects-Builderrorinconsoleoutput) and did copy the compile command and manually run it like this:

```
python "c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\titanium.CMD" "--no-colors" "--no-prompt" "build" "--platform" "android" "--sdk" "3.1.0.GA" "--log-level" "trace" "--target" "emulator" "--android-sdk" "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk" "--avd-id" "2" "--avd-abi" "armeabi" "--avd-skin" "HVGA" "--skip-js-minify"
```

but python gives me this error:

```
File "c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\titanium.CMD", line 1
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong? Where is the roblem?

**Additional Info:**
I'm using latest version of Titanium Studio (build: 3.1.0.201304151600) on my Windows Server 2008 R2;
I have `node.js`, `npm`, `node.acs`, `python` installed on my system and environmental variables are correct and working;
I have Android SDK for both `android-2.2` and `android-17` versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of searching and seeking through too many similar problems without answers, I fixed it by myself.
For everyone who is facing errors starting with `[ERROR] error: more than one emulator` in Titanium Studio, the problem can be because of one of the following reasons:

- You have an Android device connected to your computer
- You have an Android Simulator application like **BlueStacks**.

My error was because of BlueStacks running in background.

Comment: Cool, coding with titanium is like fighting an full packed army with no weapons.... real challenging most of the times.

Answer (score 2):

## Answer 1 :

Seems build tools got moved to another directory with the latest Android SDK update. Created symlinks to aapt and dx in /Applications/Android-sdk/platform-tools:

```
ln -s /Applications/Android-sdk/build-tools/17.0.0/aapt aapt ln -s /Applications/Android-sdk/build-tools/17.0.0/dx dx
```

This solved it for me (after some digging in their Python code).

## Answer 2 :

I'm on windows so i used mklink. I had to add a link to lib/dx.jar for it to work. What I dit was first add folder 'lib' to platform-tools folder and after in command line:

```
cd %YOUR_ANDROID_DIR%\platform-tools    
mklink aapt.exe ..\build-tools\android-4.2.2\aapt.exe
mklink dx.bat ..\build-tools\android-4.2.2\dx.bat      
cd lib                              
mklink dx.bat ..\..\build-tools\android-4.2.2\lib\dx.jar
```

## Answer 3 :

I copied the following files:

```
C:\Android\build-tools\17.0.0\aapt.exe to C:\Android\platform-tools\aapt.exe
C:\Android\build-tools\17.0.0\dx.bat  to  C:\Android\platform-tools\dx.bat
C:\Android\build-tools\17.0.0\lib  to  C:\Android\platform-tools\lib
```

I then cleaned the project and rebuilt and everything is now working.

Source here : http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/152497/titanium-sdk-310-error-typeerror-argument-of-type-nonetype-is-not-iterable-on-building-android-app#comment-175782

Answer (score 1):

Though it should be a comment, thought of answering it.

1. Did you delete your build folder and try to re-deploy.
2. Try to compile in previous versions of titanium sdk? If you did try, did u get the same error.

**If these does not work, try to...**

1. Try to install platform tools from android sdk.
2. Also check your JDK version in command line, sometimes this can be crazy one as your environment variable might be pointing to different JDK path altogether which you might be not be using with Titanium.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I did all you suggestions, cleaned build folders, tried other versions of titanium sdk and the error is the same usually with small differences

Comment: I can't find platform tools in android sdk manager, there are `Android SDK Tools` and `SDK Platform`for each version which are installed.

Comment: my java version is `1.6.0_25`

Comment: Can you open u r SDK manager and update them? there should be platform tools folder inside your SDK...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to fix it and I wrote the answer myself.